# Beginning an openGL project with XCode. Error: "ld: library not found for -lglfw3.3.1"

Tags: xcode, opengl

I am beginning openGL in xcode. I followed the instructions on how to begin detailed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3lIDsSIm6M&list=LLM1D5c_QO_ZvwkVuKD4_oBw&index=1).

In short, I linked the libglfw3.3.1.dylib, libGLEW.1.13.0.dylib and OpenGL framework under build settings, and added /usr/local/include to header search paths.

However, I run into the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lglfw3.3.1
```

I saw other posts about 'library not found' errors recommending linking the frameworks which I assumed to have done from build settings with the 3 libraries mentioned above.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `/usr/local/lib` to your library search paths as well, assuming that you have installed GLFW there, and assuming that it is in fact `libglfw3.3.1.dylib` or `libglfw3.3.1.a` that you have installed there.